# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently having this error produced when I want to insert data from an entry in my tkinter program. I do not know what is the error and I am having trouble understanding this error.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox as ms
    from tkinter import ttk
    import sqlite3
    from PIL import Image,ImageTk
    import datetime

    with sqlite3.connect('Gym.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()

    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PaymentInfo (FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, CardNumber TEXT NOT NULL, NameCard TEXT NOT NULL, ExpiryDate TEXT NOT NULL, CVC TEXT NOT NULL);')

        class main:
            def __init__(self,master):


                self.master = master
                # Some Usefull variables
                self.FirstName = StringVar()
                self.LastName = StringVar()

                self.n_FirstName = StringVar()
                self.n_LastName = StringVar()

                self.CardNumber = StringVar()
                self.NameCard = StringVar()
                self.ExpiryDate = StringVar()
                self.cvc = StringVar()

                self.n_CardNumber = StringVar()
                self.n_NameCard = StringVar()
                self.n_ExpiryDate = StringVar()
                self.n_cvc = StringVar()

def payment_insert(self):

        with sqlite3.connect('Gym.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        sql2 = "INSERT INTO 'PaymentInfo' (FirstName, LastName,CardNumber,NameCard,ExpiryDate,CVC) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        c.execute(sql2,(self.n_FirstName.get(),self.n_LastName.get(),self.n_CardNumber.get(),self.n_NameCard.get(),self.n_ExpiryDate,self.n_cvc.get()))

        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

Comment: `self.n_ExpiryDate` should be `self.n_ExpiryDate.get()` in `c.execute(sql2, ....)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expiry Date TEXT NOT NULL` part of your `PaymentInfo` table creation statement

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PaymentInfo (FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, CardNumber TEXT NOT NULL, NameCard TEXT NOT NULL, Expiry Date TEXT NOT NULL, CVC TEXT NOT NULL);')
```

is not correct.

Going by the insert query

```
sql2 = "INSERT INTO 'PaymentInfo' (FirstName, LastName,CardNumber,NameCard,Expiry,CVC) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

it seems the column name is `Expiry`.

So, if the column name is "Expiry" and data type is `Date`, then column definition should look like: `Expiry Date NOT NULL`

---

And you might want to convert `self.n_ExpiryDate` into appropriate Python object which is compatible with Sqlite3 `Date` format before running insert query.

**Update as per edit to Question**:

If the column name is "Expiry Date" and data type is `TEXT`, then column definition should look like: `"Expiry Date" TEXT NOT NULL`.